# Sensitivity Analysis selection for nested data?

Tags: r, nested-data, nested-models, sensitivity-analysis

So the data I'm working with is GPS tracking data of pelicans and Offshore rigs with the goal of seeing if pelicans are positively or negatively affected to the presence of rigs. But before I can do any analyses on that, I need to figure out the size of the "interaction range" for the rigs. I want to do a sensitivity analysis to see at what radii does the percentage of gps points a pelican is within the interacting range of a platform.

I initially tried doing an anova/tukey hsd but the anova gave back NA's and I also realized that the data was nested and thus probably not good for anova. However I'm not sure what a better alternative would be for this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I'm currently working with one pelican to practice with the picture is of the table of the proportion of points within the interaction radius at each distance. My apologies, I'm not too sure on how to upload a usable table as I'm new to posting questions on here.

I've tried an anova and tuskey hsd, I googled around a bit and some site suggest a lm, but I don't know if that's good for this. What I hope is to find an analysis that shows at which distance does increasing the radii doesn't significantly add to the proportion of gps pings near a rig.

[image]